# How do I make my computer do this calculation and which programming language do I have to use?

Tags: math

I need an equation which finds all solutions to an inequality. For example: `5x+4y+3z+3a+3b>40`. The 5 unknowns, `x`, `y`, `z`, `a`, and `b` must be taken from `4.0`, `3.5`, `3.0`, `2.5`, `2.0`, `1.5`, `1.0`, `0.5`, and `0.0`.  For instance `x=4`, `y=4`, `z=1`, `a=1`, `b=1` is one probability but there are many more.  How can I make my computer find all of them?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a program that will tell you the least amount of work you have to do to get a total GPA of > 40.

Comment: Lets say I want 2.00 gpa then my grades will be x y z a b and my credits are 5,4,3,3,3 respectively then the equation is like this (5x+4y+3z+3a+3b)/18)>2.00 then 5x+4y+3z+3a+3b>36 So how can I find each possibilities for x y z a b ????? :(

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is to figure out how to loop through all the possibilities.  In most languages, you'll be stuck with five for loops.  Python lets you use `itertools.product` to accomplish this:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from itertools import product

for g in product(range(9),repeat=5):
    if 5*g[0]+4*g[1]+3*g[2]+3*g[3]+3*g[4] > 80:
        print([x/2 for x in g])
```

Instead of 0-4 by .5, I doubled everything to be an integer.  You may want to rethink things though.  `./gpa.py | wc` tells me that you'll get over 20k possible solutions.  (And if you only need to find the number of solutions, and not list them, then that may simplify your job.)

Comment: When I wrote this to python [0, 1, 3, 4, 4] is a solution but if i think like y = 1 and z=4 a=4 b=4 then the result is false. it is not >80 :(

Comment: `[0,1,3,4,4]` with a value of `5*0+4*1+3*3+3*4+3*4=37` is not a solution (and `z=3`).  And it would correspond to `g=[0,2,6,8,8]`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this is an integer programming problem (a special case of linear programming). A web search should turn up a lot of hits. It is generally a very difficult problem to solve; my advice is to use a package such as GLPK. Integer programming is very widely useful, so even if this particular problem is limited in scope, it's very much worth your time to figure out how to solve it, so you can apply integer programming to other problems you might encounter.